# Wrong particle spawning position

Tags: rendering, particles

I have a topping on donuts which are made using particles

- Viewport mode. If I change some parameters in the particle system, they are spawning correctly.
- Render mode they all spawn on some exact faces or just don't spawn at all.  This is incorrect.

This is the picture in the viewport:

[image: Viewport]

and this is how they look in the final render:

[image: Final render]

Comment: I see two images of Object mode, or I do not understand the images.  Can you show the actual render? I do not see it.

Comment: I am only guessing at the Russian in the screen capture.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume the donut has the same number of particles for the animation.

Make sure the lifetime is large enough such as 400 frames.
If I wanted to see all Particles visible from frame 1 to 400

- All the particles could be emitted in Frames 1 to 2. (Quick Birth)
- Lifetime can be large as in 400
- I might [bake] the particles.  I might save, close, and open,  the file to refresh.  Particles can sometimes be out of synchronization.  Sometimes change a value by a small amount might help or running the animation from frame 1.
- Ezvinete. Ya ne ponimaish pa Russki.